# SVG adding white space between layers

Tags: svg, adobe-illustrator

I have a jpg file that I need to turn into a responsive image map.  I'm trying to do this by converting it to a SVG.

In photoshop, I cut out each linkable area and pasted it as a new layer.  I then opened the psd file in Illustrator, added the links to the various layers' attribute panel, then exported it to SVG.

In Illustrator, the file looks fine.  However, when I open the SVG file in a browser, the clickable layers don't line up and creates white space.

How do I properly export this image so all the layers line up nicely.
[image: Example of spacing issue]

Comment: It's hard to determine what's wrong with an imaginary SVG. Please create a [mcve].  But you don't need to cut up your image anyway. Just put your JPEG in an SVG. Then add some transparent shapes (eg. rectangles) where you want the links to be.

Comment: I tried uploading a .ai file to show how it looked, but it won't allow those types of files.  I tried just putting transparent rectangles over the jpg and saving it as a SVG.  That worked.  I just had to add to change the exported CSS style for rectangles from fill:none to fill:transparent.  Seems to work.  Thanks very much.

Answer (score -1):

Solution:

1. Pasted jpg into .ai file.
2. Created transparent rectangles where I wanted the links to be.
3. Rectangles were created on separate layers.
4. In attributes panel for each rectangle, I set the image map to rectangle/polygon and added the respective URL.
5. Clicked File -> Save As -> SVG to export as svg file with code.

Initially the clickable areas still wouldn't work.  To solve that, in the svg code, I changed fill:none to fill:transparent.

I also experimented with `fill:#hexcolor` and `fill-opacity:0.3` so that the clickable areas where visible.